# Codeigniter how to retrieve data depending on date?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I have a question, im trying to create this function, so I will be able to load specific data depending on the date, for example:
Today: 18-Jun-2013
Record in DB: 18-Jun-1999
If today is June 18th i will like to load in my view just 1 record that matches this criteria. I have some historic dates that i would like to present on the view depending the actual day. Here's the function on the model:

```
function get_date(){

        $t = date('d-M-y');
        list($day,$month,$year) = explode("-",$t);
        $dm = $day.'-'.$month;

        $query = $this->db->query("select * from h_table where (select to_char(historic_date, 'DD-MON')) = '".$dm."' ");
            return $query;
    }
```

Im trying to extract the day & month of the current date and match it with the date on my table, but here comes the tricky part, I have to extract the day & month of the records on the DB first, my function is returning an error, I dont need the years. can somebody give me an idea? thanks
Im using an Oracle DB and codeigniter 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define a separate  function for this. You can achieve this using the following query.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM h_table WHERE CONCAT(MONTH(historic_date),'-',DAY(historic_date)) = '".date('m-d')."'");
```

Comment: But i need to compare both day & month together, not just the day, thanks anyway

Comment: Nop it doesnt, are u sure this is compatible with Oracle?